# React AG Grid: cellRendererFactory disappears when moving to v25

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm attempting to upgrade Ag Grid from v24 to v25.  There's been an an undocumented removal of the cellRendererFactory component of the grid api; it [just](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/v24.1.0/dist/lib/gridApi.d.ts) [disappeared](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/v25.0.0/dist/lib/gridApi.d.ts).

I rely on that function in the following code, to see what the autoHeightCalculator would've calculated as the height for my rows:

```
const getRowHeight = ({ node, data, api, context }) => {
    const pixelsPerEvent = 24;
    const numEventsByClass = entityClass.map(ec => Object.keys(data).includes(ec.name) ? data[ec.name].length : 0);
    const maxEventsInCell = Math.max(...numEventsByClass, 1);
// This line uses the missing API function
    const autoHeightValue = api.cellRendererFactory.gridOptionsWrapper.autoHeightCalculator.getPreferredHeightForRow(node);
    return Math.max(maxEventsInCell * pixelsPerEvent, autoHeightValue);
}
```

Is there a new feature that I should use to replace this?